# How to get drop shadow effect in Highchart JS?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I would like to get shadow like effect in line graphs in Highcharts. I searched for this property but couldn't find it anywhere.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using the [`shadow`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.shadow) property, like this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    shadow: {
      color: 'red',
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 5,
      opacity: 0.2,
      width: 5
    }
  }
},
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/zfscoz4f/2/

Comment: How to change the color of shadow according to the zones? (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/)

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you would probably have to do some workaround. Like a second series underneath, or using render.

Comment: @ewoldedn Got it. Thank you so much for the help.